# Calculating a 64-bit integer from 8 one-byte integers

Tags: list-manipulation, number-representation

I have 8 bytes expressed as integer values stored in a list.

They correspond to a 64-bit counter with the lowest significant byte at first position.

Here is an example what I am doing:

```
byteIntegers = {123, 12, 0, 169, 255, 20, 67, 199};

counter=Total[Table[byteIntegers[[i]]*256^(i - 1), {i, 1, 8}]]
14358343125271841915
```

How would you calculate this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
FromDigits[Reverse[byteIntegers], 256]
```

because the elements of the list can be considered digits of a number expressed in base 256.

If we did not have this function, we could also use

```
Total[byteIntegers 256^(Range@Length[byteIntegers] - 1)]
```

Whether you find this better than the `Table` version depends on taste.

Comment: I like your first solution more.

Comment: @mrz The second one is just showing what else you could do if the `FromDigits` function did not exist.  This is how I would implement it.  But your `Table` solution is more readable for those not used to the style of mine. You could change `Total@Table[...]` to `Sum[...]`, which would be shorter, but personally I don't like that because I tend to think of `Sum` as a symbolic processing function. We could also do `Total@MapIndexed[#1 256^(First[#2] - 1) &, byteIntegers]`, but it feels too convoluted to me. A similar solution can also be constructed with `MapThread`.

Comment: @mrz Finally, we could also use `Inner[#1 256^#2 &, byteIntegers, Range@Length[byteIntegers] - 1]`, which looks clever, but I need a second before I understand what it actually does. As usual, Mathematica has myriads of ways.  The two ways I like the most (after `FromDigits`, which is the clear winner) are what you showed and my second solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the additional solutions.